Gazebo diff drive plugin and reverse problem with EKF
I am using gazebo to use EKF using data from gazebo's odometry and imu plugin.
In the real robot, there is no problem, however when using gazebo with the below configuration for odometry, the corrected odometry at /odometry/filtered shows wrong results, it will not reverse, and when the robot goes in reverse /odometry/filtered will show it moving forward.
<plugin name="caretta_diff_drive" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
  <ros>
    <!-- <namespace></namespace> -->
  </ros>
  <update_rate>10</update_rate>
  <left_joint>wheel_left_joint</left_joint>
  <right_joint>wheel_right_joint</right_joint>
  <wheel_separation>0.16</wheel_separation>
  <wheel_diameter>0.0685</wheel_diameter>
  <max_wheel_torque>20</max_wheel_torque>
  <max_wheel_acceleration>1.0</max_wheel_acceleration>
  <command_topic>cmd_vel</command_topic>
  <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
  <publish_odom_tf>false</publish_odom_tf> <!-- turn off for ekf or ukf -->
  <publish_wheel_tf>false</publish_wheel_tf>
  <odometry_topic>odom</odometry_topic>
  <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
  <odometry_source>0</odometry_source> <!-- 0: encoder, 1: world, world for ekf to run -->
  <covariance_x>0.01</covariance_x>
  <covariance_y>0.0</covariance_y>
  <covariance_yaw>0.1</covariance_yaw>
  <robot_base_frame>base_footprint</robot_base_frame>
</plugin>

Here is the model responsible for the robot in gazebo: https://github.com/acadadev/rosrider_gazebo/blob/main/models/caretta/model.sdf
Here is the EKF configuration: https://github.com/acadadev/rosrider/blob/main/rosrider_node/param/ekf.yaml
The odometry produced by gazebo at /odom is always correct. However when ekf node processes it produces the wrong results, i.e. it will not go in reverse, but go in forward.
When I change the odometry source to world, ekf node will work as expected. And the reason is, the gazebo diff drive plugin generating wrong results not for odometry but the twist part. When the robot is moving reverse, the pose of odometry is correct, but sign is wrong when going in reverse direction.
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.2565591
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.00017387407442706965


Any ideas how to correct this?
Best Regards,
Can
